# find a string in a word and replace the complete word with another in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to find a string in a word and replace the whole word with another string in perl.

Eg: I have below string.

```
my $str =

<schedule environment="sit">
<hours>SIT_HR</hours>
</schedule> 
<schedule environment="uat">
<hours>UAT_HR</hours>
</schedule>
<schedule environment="prd">  
<hours>PRD_HR</hours>
</schedule>
```

I have to find *_HR and replace it with 60.

Output:

```
<schedule environment="sit">
<hours>60</hours>
</schedule> 
<schedule environment="uat">
<hours>60</hours>
</schedule>
<schedule environment="prd">  
<hours>60</hours>
</schedule>
```

Comment: Add to the question what did you try so far.

Comment: Since I'm new to perl I was jus trying to browse how to find the substr in a string while matching

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace

Answer (score 0):

Your input looks like an XML without the root tag.

I added the root tag and processed the file with [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
for /root/schedule/hours {
    if xsh:matches(., '_HR$' ) set . 60 ;
}
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm not well in XML. But i done the output what you expect.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
open('file',"file.xml");
my @file = <file>;
print @file if grep{s/.{3}_HR/60/g} @file;
```

In here i store the `file.xml` into the array `@file`.

`grep` for find the word into the array.

Then the substitution used to replace the sting in array.

Comment: In fact, it works, sorry. But, what is the usage of `@replace`? Why are you using `'file'` as a file handler instead of a lexical one? It doesn't work if there are more than one `xxx_HR` in a single line.

Comment: @M42 Thank you for capturing my mistake. I edited my answer. Try it yourself. This gives correct output also in a single line. Any name was used to the file handler so i just used the `file`. If you have any doubt in my edited question please add comment